# Where should I declare an enum class that concerns a class instantiated many times?

Tags: c++, optimization, enums

I have a class that contains a color attribute, and I want to use an enumeration to handle it. Since at runtime my program may create thousands of instances of this class, where is the best place to declare the enumeration in order to optimize memory usage ?

At the moment, my class declaration looks like this :

```
class Node
{
public :
//constructors, methods, etc...
enum class Color : char{WHITE, GREY, RED, GREEN}

protected :
//Some private attributes
Color _color = Color::WHITE;
};
```

I know this is an acceptable way to do it, my question is : will it bring performances down when i got like 100k instances of this class ?

Comment: _"will it bring performances down when i got like 100k instances of this class ?"_ Considering which alternative?

Comment: Writing my enum class declaration outside of the Node class ?

Comment: The `enum` declaration itself doesn't affect memory usage of your class at all, hence there is no difference.

Comment: That's it, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any data type, the enum *itself* won't take up storage in your objects, it's *instances* of the enum that are stored. (Regarding this, there is no difference between `enum` and `enum class`.) So moving the enum out of the class does not make any difference in this respect.

So in your case, the `color_` member takes up storage space. If there are subclasses where you don't need that, you might want to reconsider your class design. Otherwise, you are fine!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are concerned with `class` in the declaration of `enum class` vs `enum`.

The `enum class` and old style `enum` will generate exactly the same code and behave exactly the same in the "backend" of the compiler. The distinction happens in the semantic analysis (type checking) by the compiler (more strict checking compared to "traditional" `enum` types, so you can't do `int x = WHITE;` or `enum { A, B }; Color c = A;`).